# Aeson: FromJSON with nested encoded json

Tags: haskell, aeson

I have `JSON` that contains an encoded `JSON` as string in one of its properties:

```
{ 
  "firstName": "Frederick",
  "lastName": "Krueger",
  "address": "{\"street\": \"Elm Street, 13\", \"city\": \"Springwood\", \"state\": \"OH\"}"
}
```

Given that I have a data type:

```
data Address = Address { street :: String, city :: String, state :: String }
               deriving (Generic, Show)

data Person = Person { firstName :: String, lastName :: String, address :: Address }
              deriving (Generic, Show)
```

How do I implement `FromJSON` for `Person`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt using a small helper parser:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module MyModule where

import           Control.Monad
import           Data.Aeson
import           Data.Aeson.Types
import           Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as Text
import           GHC.Generics

data Address = Address
  { street :: String
  , city :: String
  , state :: String
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON Address

data Person = Person
  { firstName :: String
  , lastName :: String
  , address :: Address
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON Person where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    Person <$> o .: "firstName" <*> o .: "lastName" <*>
    (parseAddress =<< o .: "address")
  parseJSON _ = mzero

parseAddress :: Value -> Parser Address
parseAddress (String s) = do
  let maybeObject = decodeStrict (Text.encodeUtf8 s)
  case maybeObject of
    Nothing -> mzero
    Just o -> parseJSON (Object o)
parseAddress _ = mzero

testString :: ByteString
testString =
  "{\n  \"firstName\": \"Frederick\",\n  \"lastName\": \"Krueger\",\n\"address\": \"{\\\"street\\\": \\\"Elm Street, 13\\\", \\\"city\\\": \\\"Springwood\\\", \\\"state\\\": \\\"OH\\\"}\"\n}\n"
```

and running it in a repl:

```
λ> eitherDecodeStrict testString :: Either String Person
Right (Person {firstName = "Frederick", lastName = "Krueger", address = Address {street = "Elm Street, 13", city = "Springwood", state = "OH"}})
```

In brief the `Person` instance uses `=<<` operator to chain two parsers together - the one produced by `o .: "address"` and `parseAddress`. Within `parseAddress` we can then examine the value and do further processing if we see a `String`. `decodeStrict` is used to attempt decoding the string as an object and once `parseAddress` has that `parseJSON` can be used to parse that object as an `Address`.

Or as a one liner with no intermediate values:

```hs
parseAddress :: Value -> Parser Address
parseAddress (String s) =
  either (const mzero) parseJSON (eitherDecodeStrict (Text.encodeUtf8 s))
parseAddress _ = mzero
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by writing your own parser with the function `withObject`. In that function you explicitly handle your address case. Example:

```
parsePerson :: Value -> Parser Person
parsePerson = withObject "expected person"
              (\obj -> do
                 fname <- obj .: "firstName"
                 lname <- obj .: "lastName"
                 (addr :: String) <- obj .: "address"
                 let addr' = decode (BS.fromStrict $ pack addr)
                 return $ Person { firstName = fname, lastName = lname, address = fromJust addr' })

instance FromJSON Address where
    parseJSON (Object v) = Address <$>
                           v .: "street" <*>
                           v .: "city" <*>
                           v .: "state"
    parseJSON _ = empty
```

These are the necessary import I had to do:

```
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types (Parser(..), parseEither)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (pack)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
```

Note that in your code, you may want to avoid the partial function `fromJust`. A sample way of decoding your JSON string when it is stored in a file named `add.json`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  dat <- BS.readFile "./add.json"
  let val = decode dat :: Maybe Value
  print $ (parseEither parsePerson (fromJust val))
```

Output on execution:

```
sibi::jane { ~/scripts }-> ./aeson.hs
Right (Person {firstName = "Frederick", lastName = "Krueger", address = Address {street = "Elm Street, 13", city = "Springwood", state = "OH"}})
```

Comment: I see you use `fromJust` here, what happens when it is `Nothing`? Runtime exception or no parse?